How can I set-up a custom location for Office 2021 LTSC updates (X-Post)
(Cross Posted on Stack Exchange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78342564/how-can-i-set-up-a-custom-location-for-office-2021-ltsc-updates)
Afternoon all, I'm working on setting up an install process for Office 2021 LTSC on our non-networked laptops. I have the install working just fine, but I'm working on getting the Update part squared away. I have the config.xml file setup correctly and it'll search my local directory for updates but not the way I would like. My update xml code is: <Updates Enabled="TRUE" UpdatePath="C:\Patches\Laptop\Office" />
I have my parent folder C:\Patches\Laptop\Office
What I would like to have is a folder for each version. For example:
C:\Patches\Laptop\Office\v16.0.14332.20615

C:\Patches\Laptop\Office\v16.0.14332.20685

Each folder would have the installation bits, \Office\Data\...
However, if I set it up this way, the update process fails as not being able to find any media. If I just put the Office\Data\... folder at the root; C:\Patches\Laptop\Office\Office\Data...
the update will process. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?
Or do I need to conceed and just have an Office\Data\... folder that just has all the versions in the folder path (which works, however with the install bits, they all have a x64.cab that would get overwritten, making version control a little but more difficult

Do not cross-post please.

I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross posted.

By non-networked, I mean no internet access at all, so there is no polling for updates

C2R versions of Office has its own process to look for, compare and download updates.
The path you specify in .xml file should be to the subfolder includes the "Office" : C:\Patches\Laptop.
